# alternative filesystems for SSD

Tags: linux, filesystems, ssd, eee-pc

I am *tired* of watching fsck check my filesystem when my eeepc 901 shuts down abruptly due to a crash. I know that with a journaling filesystem, I won't have to wait for a check. However, I am well aware of the poor I/O performance of the SSD, so I can imagine using a journaling filesystem being even more frustrating, since there will be constant writes to the journal?

I will buy a new laptop without such a crummy ssd someday but, is there anything I can do now, on the software side of things?

Comment: What are you on now? ext2/3 are older than ext4, and ext4 was made in the knowledge of ssds.

Comment: You might also want to read [Aligning filesystems to an SSD’s erase block size](http://thunk.org/tytso/blog/2009/02/20/aligning-filesystems-to-an-ssds-erase-block-size/) by Theodore Ts'o (one the men behind *ext4*).

Comment: *"I am well aware of the poor I/O performance of the SSD"* - Are you sure? My SSD is for sure way faster than my (fake) RAID-10.

Comment: @tobylane i'm on ext2

Comment: @maaartinus This model has a 4gb master ssd, and a 16gb slave. The slave drive is much slower. http://www.shinyplastic.com/archives/05-21-2008-ultraportables-eee-pc-900-ssd-is-slow.php

Answer (score 5):

There are log-structured file systems available, like LogFS and NilFS that may be more performant on your SSD, but I'm unsure of their stability.

Comment: Is one of these FS stable by 2018 ? Is F2FS a good choice ?

Comment: @SebMa: I'm not sure what happened with any of those fliesystems, but SSDs had their performance increase to the point where it doesn't really matter anymore.

Answer (score 4):

try with `ReiserFS` - checking fs is very fast. This is my fs of choice - rock solid

Comment: But will it be constantly writing to the journal? This could be a problem since the ssd is so slow...

Answer (score 1):

Another filesystem to try is btrFS.  According to one of the main developers of ext3 and ext4, ext4 was actually intended more of a gateway between ext3 and btrFS (much like Microsoft's failed Windows ME transition from dos-based to NT-based).  btrFS is still not at a "stable" release, but I hear it is very stable.

--EDIT--
By not "stable" but stable, I mean I don't know of any serious problems that would affect someone who uses a system normally.  It's still considered a development version, but it's fairly polished.